# C++ code is giving a run-time error in the condition of for loop Whereas it is compiling correctly if it is replaced by code which makes same sense

Tags: c++, for-loop, undefined-behavior, unsigned-integer, modular-arithmetic

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
vector<int> luck;
int k = 10;
int sum = 0;
for(int  i = 0; i<5; i++) luck.push_back(i);

for(int i = 0; i<luck.size() - k; i++) sum+=luck[i]; //RUNTIME ERROR

cout<<endl<<sum;
return 0;
}
```

wheareas it is giving correct output if I add

```
int boundary = luck.size() - k;
```

and replacing the condition of second 'for' loop by

```
i<boundary;
```

Here's the complete errorless code, again:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
vector<int> luck;
int k = 10;
int sum = 0;
for(int  i = 0; i<5; i++) luck.push_back(i);

int boundary = luck.size() - k;   // HERE 
for(int i = 0; i<boundary; i++) sum+=luck[i]; //CONDITION CHANGE

cout<<endl<<sum;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't mix signed and unsigned. Also, what do you think `5 - 10` will give you? You don't have that many elements in the vector...

Comment: @DeiDei It isn't the mixing of signed and unsigned that's the problem, it's the fact unsigned is used at all to deal with natural numbers, like a number of elements in container. It's just a ridiculous design choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing unsigned and signed in your for loop. Another way to make your code work is to change:

```
for(int i = 0; i<luck.size() - k; i++) sum+=luck[i]; //RUNTIME ERROR
```

to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < int(luck.size() - k); i++) sum+=luck[i];
```

**Explanation:**

luck.size() returns unsigned integer value (std::vector::size_type). When you subtract k from it it's still treated as unsigned integer. Because in your case k > luck.size(), the result is negative. When you assign negative value to unsigned integer, you will get huge positive number instead, so the loop will not stop correctly.

In second case, assignment (to signed int) treats rhs expression as signed and code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by DeiDei, this is the result of unlucky mixing of signed and unsigned integer.

Please note, `std::vector::size()` returns [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Depending on platform, this is usally a 32 bit or 64 bit `unsigned`. (`size_t` has the same number of bits like `void*`.)

In the 1st sample:

```
for(int i = 0; i<luck.size() - k; i++) sum+=luck[i]; //RUNTIME ERROR
```

the following values occur:

`luck.size()`: (size_t)5

`k`: (int)10

`luck.size() - k`: (size_t)0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB (assuming 64 bit size)

The comparison of `i < luck.size() - k` promotes `i` to `size_t` as well. So, iteration does not stop at 5. Hence, in the 1st sample code, you get an out-of-bound access in the loop.

In the 2nd sample:

```
int boundary = luck.size() - k;   // HERE 
for(int i = 0; i<boundary; i++) sum+=luck[i]; //CONDITION CHANGE
```

the value is converted to `int` again.

`int boundary = luck.size() - k;`: (int)-5

This results simply in no iteration of loop.

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> luck;
  int k = 10;
  int sum = 0;
  for(int  i = 0; i<5; i++) luck.push_back(i);
  // trying 2nd version:
  std::cout << "2nd version:\n";
  int boundary = luck.size() - k;   // HERE 
  for(int i = 0; i<boundary; i++) {
    std::cout << "i: " << i << '\n';
    sum+=luck[i]; //CONDITION CHANGE
  }
  std::cout << "sum: " << sum << std::endl;
  // trying 1st version
  std::cout << "1st version:\n";
  sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<luck.size() - k; i++) {
    std::cout << "i: " << i << '\n';
    sum+=luck[i]; //RUNTIME ERROR
  }
  std::cout << "sum: " << sum << std::endl;
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2nd version:
sum: 0
1st version:
i: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
i: 5
i: 6
i: 7
i: 8
i: 9
i:
```

Note:

The output of `sum` doesn't happen. The application simply dies without further notification. This is one kind how undefined behavior may manifest. A segmentation fault is another.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3226c7dd696d0f9b)</kbd>

Comment: "_size_t has the same number of bits like void*_" why is that so?

Comment: @curiousguy This was my sloppy abbreviation / rule of thumb for _`std::size_t` can safely store the value of any non-member pointer, in which case it is synonymous with `std::uintptr_t`_ which in turn is an _unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer_. Do you think this was a bit too sloppy? (The quotes are from cppreference.com.)